# Is it possible with Jquery to change a class after every 5th time it is displayed on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is it possible with Jquery to change a class after every 5 times it is displayed on a page?

For example, I'm working with an api script that outputs several contact records. The API does not give me access to the area of the output of the records, but it does give me a `<div class="style-close"></div>` at the end of each set of records.

A record looks like this:

```
<div class="contact"> 
 <p>content </p>
<div class="contact-name><p>content</p></div>
<div class="contact-address><p>content</p></div>
</div>
<div class="style-close"></div>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: Show the code you're currently using to display the records on the page.

Comment: @AndyHolmes just want to put in a clear tag after every 5th record.

Comment: So is that after each 5th parent .contact?

Comment: @AndyHolmes no I just want to change the `<div class="style-close"></div>` to `<div class="clear"></div>` on the 5th one. In the stylesheet I just want to put `clear:both;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use `:nth-of-type-selector`

```
$('.style-close:nth-of-type(5n)').doSomething()
```

[:nth-of-type() Docs](http://jsfiddle.net/fLzfT/)

Note: Can also do same in css without script

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fLzfT/)**</kbd>